# Can the ASP.Net swagger UI (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen) be customized to get the credentials from the API user

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have seen a swagger UI with the Authorization button, which can get the user credentials, authorization flow, and client secrets then it will go and request the token from the auth server and use it in the next API calls. The UI is like this

[image]

I have used this approach in my ASP.net6 web API project (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen). But only manage to add a text box there to enter the bearer token, I have to get the Bearer token using a different mechanism. Can anyone help me to configure the swagger UI to something like above

Comment: check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basic-authentication-in-swagger-open-api-net-5/). if you are using basic auth in API then you can use this mechanism.

Comment: I found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122409/how-do-i-configure-swaggergen-with-openiddict-parameters-for-client-credentials